# AWS Cli Command to create elasticsearch domain gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cli

I am trying to create elasticsearch domain using AWS Cli using command :

```
aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name weblogs --elasticsearch- 
version 5.5 --elasticsearch-cluster-config  
InstanceType=m4.large.elasticsearch,InstanceCount=2 --ebs-options 
EBSEnabled=true,VolumeType=standard,VolumeSize=100 --access-policies 
'{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Action": "es:*", 
"Principal":"*","Effect": "Allow", "Condition": {"IpAddress":{"aws:SourceIp": 
["192.0.2.0/32"]}}}]}'
```

which is provided on aws documentation.
But when i am running above command its giving me following error:

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
>   [parameters] To see help text, you can run:   aws help   aws 
>   help   aws   help Unknown options: Statement:, [,
>   {, Effect:, Allow,, Principal:, {AWS:, arn:aws:iam::555555555555:root,
>   },, Action:es:*,, Resource:,
>   arn:aws:es:us-east-1:555555555555:domain/logs/*, }, ], }', 2012-10-17,

Is anyone having any idea on whats the issue and how to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the access policy statement is not correctly braced or perhaps the command is not fully executed on one line(when I copy yours it is multiline)? Try:


`aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name weblogs --elasticsearch-version 5.5 --elasticsearch-cluster-config InstanceType=m4.large.elasticsearch,InstanceCount=2 --ebs-options EBSEnabled=true,VolumeType=standard,VolumeSize=100 --access-policies '{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Action": "es:*", "Principal":"*","Effect": "Allow", "Condition": {"IpAddress":{"aws:SourceIp": ["192.0.2.0/32"]}}}]}'`

Comment: But this command is no different from what i am trying. This is also not working. What can be the issue.

Comment: The condition in the error is the same as in the command: double commas `Action:es:,,` instead of a star `*`. So either the pasted error is not right or it is _correct_ and telling you that you have something funny going on between pasting your command. Try: typing it out OR remove each of the parameters from a command and see which is the problem. Obviously start with `--access-policies `